# integrate angular2 rc with play framework 2

Tags: java, angular, playframework-2.0, sbt

I would like to integrate angular2 rc with play framework 2.

Here is an example with beta version https://github.com/joost-de-vries/play-angular2-typescript.

Unfortunately rc naming change and each angular module are in a different module. With npm everything is copy to @angular folder and modules are in there respective folder.

With this version folder modules are prefixed with angular__, for this reason systemjs config from angular doc is not working anymore.

Any know how to solve this problem or have a working example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is described in the Angular documentation. See the systemjs.config.ts file in [this Plnkr](https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/quickstart/ts/plnkr.html).

I've updated the starter project you linked to. See [here](https://github.com/joost-de-vries/play-angular2-typescript/blob/ts-20-preview/app/views/index1.scala.html).

Comment: Great thank you! The most important part is `paths": {       "*": [         "*",         "target/web/node-modules/main/webjars/*"       ]     }` line in tsconfig.json file and we need typescript v2 for that.